# Java - To find the Second Highest Digit

Tags: java

I need to:

Write a function that accepts a string and returns the second highest numerical digit in the input as an integer.

The following rules should apply:

- Inputs with no numerical digits should return -1
- Inputs with only one    numerical digit should return -1
- Non-numeric characters should be    ignored
- Each numerical input should be treat individually, meaning in the
  event of a joint highest digit then the second highest digit will
  also be the highest digit

For example:

- "abc:1231234" returns 3
- "123123" returns 3

This is my code currently:

```
public class Solution {
    public static int secondHighestDigit(String input) {

    try{

        int k = Integer.parseInt(input); 

        char[] array = input.toCharArray(); 

        int big = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int secondBig = Integer.MIN_VALUE;


        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

            System.out.println(array[i]);

            for(int n = 0; n < array[i]; n++){
                if(array[i] > big)
                {
                    secondBig = big;
                    big = array[i];
                }else if(array[i] > secondBig && array[i] != big){
                    secondBig = array[i];
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(secondBig);

        }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("-1");
    }
    return -1;
    }

}
```

Tests:

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class Tests
{

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        Solution solution = new Solution();

        assertEquals(3, solution.secondHighestDigit("abc:1231234"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2()
    {
        Solution solution = new Solution();

        assertEquals(3, solution.secondHighestDigit("123123"));
     }
}
```

The program should print 3 for abc:1231234 and 123123 but instead it is returning -1 for both.

I am lost are where to go from here. I would be grateful if someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: "Where to go from here" is a very vague question. Please try to describe what issue you are facing with your program.

Comment: The program should print 3 for abc:1231234 and 123123 but instead it is returning -1

Comment: Maybe it helps to split the problem into smaller ones. We need to split the string into its parts. We need to detect if it is a number. We need to collect these in a list. Then sort the list. Then find the last and the second last item in that list. And then we would have very specific questions to ask for.

Comment: Well that's kind of basic, you are only returning a hardcoded -1 from your method. You need to add another return statement earlier in the method.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Where should I put this Return statement and what should the value of this be? Thanks.

Comment: @Phenj: hint: you've got two different `System.out.println` statements in your method, but only one `return`. I guess you'd want to return the same value that you print in both cases ...

Comment: Looks like HackerRank problem to me!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am sorry but I do not understand what your trying to tell me. Am I returning at the wrong place?

Comment: You can have multiple return statements in a method

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am returning secondBig just above the catch now but it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to remove all non numeric characters and sort the string

```
public int secondGreatest(String s) {
    String newStr = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]*", "");
    if (newStr.isEmpty() || newStr.length() == 1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        char[] c = newStr.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(c);
        return c[newStr.length() - 2] - '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I am getting an error when it trys "Arrays.sort(c);" It says Solution.java:9 error: cannot find symbol. Arrays.sort(c); EDIT: Just needed to import Java arrays.

Comment: Would you be open to a DM?

Comment: Sorry, but what's a DM ?

Comment: Hi. It means Direct Message. I just wanted to know if you could explain to me what this line of code does? `return c[newStr.length() - 2] - '0';` I am just curious is all because I don't understand what the `-2] '0';` means. Thanks.

Comment: I sent a message above but forgot to @ you.

Comment: @ZoomingZoomZoomer this is simple, after sorting the array  of characters in non decreasing order, the before last element of the array is the second greatest. why I subtract '0' from it because we want the value to be integer, characters in java are 2 byte size and all have unicode value, the unicode value of the digits are consecutive, means  '0' = 48, '1'=49, ..., '9'=57. if we do '5' - '0' = 53 - 48 = 5, '1' - '0' = 49 - 48 = 1 ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to convert your string to an Integer at first - since you already know that it's possible it may contain some non-numeric characters.

Instead, parse through each character in the String, if it is an integer, add it to a list of integers. Let's use an ArrayList so we can add to the list and have it dynamically sized.

Your code should look something like this: (giving you some work to do)

```
// Iterate through characters in the string
// You could also use "substring" so you don't have to deal with chars
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
  char c = s.charAt(i);        
  if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
    // Convert c to an int appropriately and add it to your list of ints
  }
}

// Sort the list of ints in descending order

// Now, we write a seperate method
public int getNthBiggest(int n) {
  // Return the nth biggest item (you could just use 2)
}
```

Checking if the string has 0 or 1 "digits" should be trivial enough for you, if you've gotten this far.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code:

private static int secondHighestDigit(String input) {

```
    String pattern = "(\\d+)";
    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
    if (m.find( )) {
        String foundedDigits = m.group(0);
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
        char[] characters = foundedDigits.toCharArray();
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(char c : characters){
            integers.add(Integer.parseInt(c +""));
        }
        if(integers.size()==1)
            return -1;
        Collections.sort(integers);
        System.out.println("One Biggest int: " + integers.get(integers.size()-1));
        System.out.println("Two Biggest int: " + integers.get(integers.size()-2));
        return integers.get(integers.size()-2);
    }else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        return -1;
    }
}
```